# Would it be correct or incorrect to interpret Aristotle's view of Tragedy as a ritual?

Tags: aristotle

My question relates specifically to the use of the Greek verb

[δρώντων](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=drw%2Fntwn&la=greek&can=drw%2Fntwn0&prior=mori/ois&d=Perseus:text:1999.01.0055:section=1449b&i=1)    part pl pres act masc gen attic epic doric aeolic contr

in [Poetics, 1449b-28](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0056%3Asection%3D1449b) in which tragedy is defined, among other things as a representation of action/people acting.

The verb is shown to be used in [two ways](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=drw%2Fntwn&la=greek&can=drw%2Fntwn0&prior=mori/ois&d=Perseus:text:1999.01.0055:section=1449b&i=1#lexicon): Action, and Action in a ritual context. Would an application of the second use be correct or at least possibly correct in this particular case, thus defining tragedy as a representation of ritual action?

Alternatively, to what extent was the use of the word by later authors who used it specifically in the ritual sense (eg Iamblichus, Pausanius, Plutarch) a reference to the earlier usage?

Answer (score 2):

In the specific context it means "actors", persons that display actions.

"δρώντων καὶ οὐ δι' ἀπαγγελίας" by actions and not via reciting

I translate from wiki dictionary (Greek) (modern meaning)

drama < from the ancient Greek word drama < act

> noun:
>   1. poetic genre of ancient Greek literature that includes the tragedy, comedy and satirical drama 
>   2. theatrical or cinematic work with strong passions and conflicts misery, 
>   3. passions of a man or a whole group of people living drama

https://el.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B4%CF%81%CE%AC%CE%BC%CE%B1

From Greek Wikipedia: Article drama (δράμα)

> The drama is a kind of ancient Greek poetry that synthesizes elements
>   from both prior periods, the epic and lyric poetry.
>
> The word drama in the new Greek language means unpleasant event or
>   undesirable situation.
>
> As for the ancient Greek culture, the word has a completely different
>   meaning. Etymologically derived from the verb drao-oh, therefore means
>   the kind of poetry accompanied by a representation of actions (as
>   opposed to the epic and lyric poetry).
>
> Born and developed in Attica of the celebrations in honor of the god
>   Dionysus, which are offered to it many dramatic elements (the events).
>   Started by the original song, the dithyramb (διθύραμβος), sung during
>   the worship of the god Dionysus and accompanied by flute and
>   orchestral or mimic movements. After its
>   completion by Lasso of the Hermione, the music lover tyrant of Athens
>   Peisistratos introduced in magnificent festivities which he
>   established it, the Great Dionysia.
>
> The types of drama are three: comedy, tragedy, satirical drama

so because the drama is developed from the ceremonies in honor of Dionysus it can be said that it originates from "rituals" but during its development it has transformed to a expression/artistic medium. The significance of the beliefs regarding Dionysus is quite complicated, and has influenced both demystification but also mystical-religious thinking (see Orphism for an example).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dithyramb

https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%94%CF%81%CE%AC%CE%BC%CE%B1_%28%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%B3%CE%BF%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%87%CE%BD%CE%AF%CE%B1%29

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drama

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dionysia

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphism_%28religion%29

---

δρώμενο < δρώμενα < ancient Greek δρώμενα, neuter gender of δρώμενος, 
participle perfect tense passive of the verb δράω / δρῶ

(δρώμενο) happening  (usually plural: events)

1. spectacle (sometimes dramatized) religious
2. something that takes place, some events or shows, usually artistic, political or social

Answer (score 1):

The Greek verb "drao" means to do, to act. It has no affinity to a ritual context. In the context of Poetics 1449, b28 it definitely does **not** mean "to act during a ritual".

Because the content of Greek tragedies can be any action. The emphasis is even on non-ritual actions, cf. Oedipus the King by Sophokles, a paradigm of Aristotle.

Greek tragedies were performed during regular festivals. They were submitted to a tragedy contest, not to a ritual.